# DLL size - how do I get a bird-eye view of the DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, size

I compile a C/C++ DLL in VS2015, it quite big, composed from many sub-projects, and I am looking to reduce its size.
But for that, I need a bird-eye view on what is taking all that space.

Is there a utility that let me see that?

Anticipating questions:
No, I don't want to compress it. I'm trying to reduce mainly in-memory size.
Yes, I know about stripping. beside that.
Yes, I'm building Release.

Comment: And yes, someone has voted to close your question only 3 minutes after it was posted, because they didn't have an answer to it, or possibly because they couldn't even read it... very typical to this website.

Comment: Generate a map file and see how big each section is and what it contains.

Comment: Yes, the linker's .map file tells you exactly what got linked into the executable.  Interpreting it and finding *practical* ways to eliminate what it think it needed, well, that's not so simple.  It does forever boil down to "use less libraries, write less code, stop fretting about a megabyte".  The linker doesn't suck.  And the amount of memory you need rarely has anything to do with the executable image size, use a memory profiler.